# In ubuntu 64 bit the eclipse kepler j2ee projects not deploying to tomcat7 web giving error Http 404 error

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am trying to run a dynamic web project with eclipse kepler as IDE and tomcat 7 as server and i configured eclipse to use tomcat but when i am trying to run project from eclipse 
getting error in web page ..

---

HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource (/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.26

---

I think the project is not deploying to tomcat web directory from eclipse wtpwebapps

Comment: Is the mapping to the URL correct.?

Comment: when we start project from eclipse it auotmatically redirect to that url so no problem with url ,may the deployment is the problem ..

Comment: Mapping can be a reason. It isn't like that. If your application starts with `/` , it means you've specified it in `web.xml`. Check for the mappings to `/`. If you are sure deployment is the problem open tomcat manager and verify.

Comment: @user2339071 Thank you it's working by typing the full url but i want index.jsp as defualt handler like http://localhost:8080/Demo/  can you tell me exact mapping for this

Comment: You can specify the `jsp/html file` in `web.xml` under the `<welcome-file-list>` </br> `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>` </br>`</welcome-file-list>` tag.

Comment: done same but not working ,one more problem for demo project  it's working ,i have another project in other server exported as war file no trying to run in my system same error getting ..

Comment: Probably some environment setup issue.